# How to call cy.json to get position data

Tags: cytoscape.js

In cytoscape.js, I would like to save the graph data to restore later, including positions. 
I am calling cy.json after graph render, I think, but the positions are still empty. 
Here is my call, which dumps the json into a div on the page:

```
  layout:{ name: 'cose',
        stop:function(){
            $("#json").html(JSON.stringify(cy.json()));
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Positions are stored in the element JSON: http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json